# customise only one section

Tags: titlesec

I have already asked this question but I have not received answers.
I tried to find a solution but I still have problems.

I want to make a document in which all the sections appear with a style and only one section appear with different style, for that I realized two styles of section but my problem is that I do not arrive to put it in the same document.

Here is the code of my section that appear with different style (section two):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{0088FF}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAP 1}
    \section{Section one}
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}%
    {\rlap{\color{myBlue}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}\colorbox{myBlue}{%
            \raisebox{0pt}[13pt][3pt]{ \makebox[70pt]{% height, width
                    \fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\color{white}{\thesection}}
    }}}%
    {15pt}%
    { \color{myBlue}#1
        %
    }
    \section{Section two}
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[1]
    \titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}{#1}
    {}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}
\end{document}
```

[image]

for the sections one, three and four i want use this code :

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-12pt \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
{2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\fontfamily{pag}\bfseries\color{myBlue}}}
```

[image]

I want the final result to be like this picture :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create commands (named `\setupnormalsections` and `\setupspecialsections` here) that use `\titleformat` to change how section titles are formatted, and call these commands in the middle of your document.

Don't forget that you have to use `##` in a macro definition if you want the macro to insert a `#` when it is expanded. You need this to pass `#1` *as is* in the fifth mandatory argument of `\titleformat`. Without the two `#`, wherever the macro replacement text reads `#1`, expanding the macro would replace this `#1` with the macro's first argument. First, this is not desired here. Second, the macros in question here are `\setupnormalsections` and `\setupspecialsections`; they take no argument.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{0088FF}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\setupnormalsections}{%
  \titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\fontfamily{pag}\bfseries\color{myBlue}}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}{##1}
    {}%
}

\newcommand*{\setupspecialsections}{%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]
    {\Large\bfseries\sffamily\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}%
    {\rlap{\color{myBlue}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}\colorbox{myBlue}{%
      \raisebox{0pt}[13pt][3pt]{\makebox[70pt]{% height, width
          \fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\color{white}{\thesection}}%
      }}}%
    {15pt}%
    {\color{myBlue}##1}%
}

\makeatother

\setupnormalsections

\begin{document}

    \chapter{CHAP 1}
    \section{Section one}

    \setupspecialsections
    \section{Section two}

    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[1]

    \setupnormalsections
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you very mutch @frougon

Comment: By the way, the visual design of your section titles is nice!

Comment: ok, thank you very mutch